# how to await AWS assumeRole and then carry on with module definition

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-sdk

I'm trying to create a module that exports some functions and variables but before it can do any of that it must switch user roles.  Here is the code I've tried.  I would like the anonymous async function to happen first and everything that comes after waits for that to complete, otherwise the other requests won't have the permissions to complete.

As it is now I'm getting an access denied error because `listQueues` is being called before `assumeRole` completes.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({region: 'eu-west-1'});
var sts = new AWS.STS();
var sqs;

(async () => {
  let role_promise = await sts.assumeRole({
    RoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::xxxx:role/UserRole',
    RoleSessionName: 'NodeDeveloperRoleSession'
  }).promise().then(data => {
    console.log('Assumed role success :)');
    AWS.config.update({
      accessKeyId: data.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
      secretAccessKey: data.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
      sessionToken: data.Credentials.SessionToken
    });
    sqs = new AWS.SQS({apiVersion: '2012-11-05'});
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log('Cannot assume role :(');
    console.log(err, err.stack);
  })
})();

async function list_queues() {
  let result = await sqs.listQueues({}).promise();
  return result.QueueUrls;
}

const result = list_queues();
exports.queues;
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 6):

There are couple of mistakes that you're making while assuming the role and using that credential to access other resources.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({region: 'eu-west-1'});
var sts = new AWS.STS();
var sqs;

(async () => {
  let role_promise = await sts.assumeRole({
    RoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::xxxx:role/UserRole',
    RoleSessionName: 'NodeDeveloperRoleSession'
  }).promise().then(data => {
    console.log('Assumed role success :)');

    /* here you are making AWS globally to use your assume role, 
       this will make subsequent call error prone, may or may not work
       depending on how you are making call 
   */

    AWS.config.update({
      accessKeyId: data.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
      secretAccessKey: data.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
      sessionToken: data.Credentials.SessionToken
    });

    sqs = new AWS.SQS({apiVersion: '2012-11-05'});

  }).catch(err => {
    console.log('Cannot assume role :(');
    console.log(err, err.stack);
  })
})();

async function list_queues() {
  let result = await sqs.listQueues({}).promise();
  return result.QueueUrls;
}

const result = list_queues();
exports.queues;
```

This is what I think is better way to `assume role` and use any resources you want :

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({region: 'eu-west-1'});
var sts = new AWS.STS();
var sqs;

(async () => {
  let role_promise = await sts.assumeRole({
    RoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::xxxx:role/UserRole',
    RoleSessionName: 'NodeDeveloperRoleSession'
  }).promise().then(data => {
    console.log('Assumed role success :)');

    /* 
      It will use your AWS assume role credential and will not set it globally,
      Which means you can access resources of multiple account in same function 
      likewise.
   */
    var creds = new AWS.Credentials({
        accessKeyId: data.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
        secretAccessKey: data.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
        sessionToken: data.Credentials.SessionToken
    });

    /* now use creds to create object of the resources that you want to access from 
       that account */
   // Also, in this case using endpoint is advisable
   // I have set it to us-east-2, you can use any endpoint where your service is
    sqs = new AWS.SQS({apiVersion: '2012-11-05', credentials:  creds, endpoint: 'sqs.us-east-2.amazonaws.com'});

  }).catch(err => {
    console.log('Cannot assume role :(');
    console.log(err, err.stack);
  })
})();

async function list_queues() {
  let result = await sqs.listQueues({}).promise();
  return result.QueueUrls;
}

const result = list_queues();
exports.queues;
```

**Read below documentation for more use cases**

[More on Credential](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Credentials.html) 
[AWS regions and endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical js asycn timing issue. You call an `IIFE`, which is your `(async () => {...})();` first, then the `list_queues()` in the callstack will happen first because the `sts.assumeRole(...)` call is asynchronous. Another thing is since you already use async/await, then you do not have to use `.then()`, just use `await` directly to avoid neste callback.

Correct way:

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({ region: 'eu-west-1' });
const sts = new AWS.STS();
let queues;

(async () => {
  try {
    const data = await sts.assumeRole({
      RoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::xxxx:role/UserRole',
      RoleSessionName: 'NodeDeveloperRoleSession'
    }).promise();
    console.log('Assumed role success :)');
    AWS.config.update({  // or you can init your SQS with this Credential
      accessKeyId: data.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
      secretAccessKey: data.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
      sessionToken: data.Credentials.SessionToken
    });
    const sqs = new AWS.SQS({ apiVersion: '2012-11-05' });
    const result = await sqs.listQueues({}).promise();
    queues = result.QueueUrls;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Cannot assume role :(');
    console.log(err, err.stack);
  }
})();

exports = queues;
```